# Replace specific file lines by groovy

Tags: groovy

I have 2 files (`long.xml` and `sort.xml` file) with the same format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<psf version="2.0">
<provider id="org.eclipse.team.cvs.core.cvsnature">
<project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynBusStop,Account Interest,Account Interest,branch_A_B"/>
<project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynInf,ActiveMQ Libraries,ActiveMQ Libraries,branch_A_B"/>
<project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynBusStop,Alert,Alert,branch_B_B"/>
<project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynBusStop,Alert Adaptor,Alert Adaptor,branch_A_B"/>
<project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynInf,Ant Extensions Syn,Ant Extensions Syn,branch_A_B"/>
</provider>
</psf>`
```

everything in `sort.xml` should be in `long.xml`.

I want to write a `script` to lookup sort.xml so that I can update new information from `sort.xml` to `long.xml` (usually update branches). This is my script:

```
def source = new File('Path:\\sort.xml')
def dest = new File('Path:\\long.xml')
text = dest.text
text.eachLine
{

    if(it.contains("/cvs/SynBusStop,Account Interest,"))
    {
        println it
        text = text.replace("branch_A_B", "new_Branch")
        dest.write(text);
    }   

}
```

`

But it has replaced every line containing `branch_A_B`. Could anyone can help me in this case, I am a newbie in Groovy, Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess that this is not the way to go.. XML parsing seems to be better idea.

Comment: Agreed, this really isn't the route to take...  Parse both files (`XmlSlurper`?) and then manipulate one of them

Comment: Can you show your inputs and expected outputs? Maybe someone can then come up with a non-brittle solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are using the `replace` method on the whole file text. You should do it only on the line you want it:

```
def source = new File('Path:\\sort.xml')
def dest = new File('Path:\\long.xml')
def newLines = []

dest.eachLine { line ->
    if(line.contains("/cvs/SynBusStop,Account Interest,")) {
        println line
        line = line.replace("branch_A_B", "new_Branch")
    }
    newLines << line
}

dest.withWriter { out ->
    newLines.each { out.println it }
}
```

Regarding the differences between the two files, it depends a lot on how generic you want the solution to be. Maybe you can solve it in a *classic way* with [*diff and patch*](http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html). If the files are not big you can store lines in a `Map` and compare or you can make it more specific [processing XML](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have `text = text.replace("branch_A_B", "new_Branch")` which will indeed replace all occurrences in the whole file.

If you want to carry on with your strategy rather than experiencing with XML Parsing, you can try by replacing row by row. Something like this:

def strIn = """
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            `
        """

```
    def strOut ="";

    strIn.eachLine{
        println "-->"+it
        if(it.contains("/cvs/SynBusStop,Account Interest,"))
        {
            it = it.replace("branch_A_B", "new_Branch")
            println "-->CHANGED: "+it
        }
        strOut+=it+"\n";
    }

    println "Result: "+strOut
```

which outputs:

```
-->
-->         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-->         <psf version="2.0">
-->         <provider id="org.eclipse.team.cvs.core.cvsnature">
-->         <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynBusStop,Account Interest,Account Interest,branch_A_B"/>
-->CHANGED:             <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynBusStop,Account Interest,Account Interest,new_Branch"/>
-->         <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynInf,ActiveMQ Libraries,ActiveMQ Libraries,branch_A_B"/>
-->         <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynBusStop,Alert,Alert,branch_B_B"/>
-->         <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynBusStop,Alert Adaptor,Alert Adaptor,branch_A_B"/>
-->         <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynInf,Ant Extensions Syn,Ant Extensions Syn,branch_A_B"/>
-->         </provider>
-->         </psf>`
-->     
Result: 
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <psf version="2.0">
            <provider id="org.eclipse.team.cvs.core.cvsnature">
            <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynBusStop,Account Interest,Account Interest,new_Branch"/>
            <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynInf,ActiveMQ Libraries,ActiveMQ Libraries,branch_A_B"/>
            <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynBusStop,Alert,Alert,branch_B_B"/>
            <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynBusStop,Alert Adaptor,Alert Adaptor,branch_A_B"/>
            <project reference="1.0,:pserver:url:/cvs/SynInf,Ant Extensions Syn,Ant Extensions Syn,branch_A_B"/>
            </provider>
            </psf>`
```